# K&R C Histogram

Tags: c, histogram

I'm currently doing exercise 1-13 in K&R's C the Programming Language 2nd edition. I decided to start with a simple histogram that just replaces each letter in a word with '*'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// histogram

#define IN 1
#define OUT 0

main() {
  int c, state;
  state = OUT;

  while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == '\n' || c == '\t' || c == ' ') {
      state = OUT;
      putchar('\n');
    }
    else {
      if (c != '\n' || c != ' ' || c != '\t') {
        state = IN;
        putchar('*');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, take a look at this snippet of code:

```
 else {
   if (c != '\n' || c != ' ' || c != '\t') {
     state = IN;
     putchar('*');
   }
 }
```

How come this works, but if I enter `if (state != OUT)` , it doesn't work? I end up getting a completely different output. Aren't those two statements essentially the same thing?

Comment: Aren't which two statements essentially the same thing?

Comment: Just run through some simple examples. Consider an input line with a single letter followed by a newline. `state` starts with value `OUT`. The first `getchar` reads the letter. The code shown will output `*`. Your version of the code will output nothing (since `if (state != OUT)` will be false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c` being equal to three terms "or" each other is not equivalent `c` not being equal to the negations of the same three terms "or" each other.

See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).